# How to determine when .tv domain is going to expire

Tags: dns

I lost a .tv domain and really need it back. It is now in `pendingDelete` state. Its expire date was 2019-02-03T20:44:30Z.

Here, the status codes are explained: https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en. According to that, the domain should be already available. Is there any way of calculating when the domain is going to release?

And for my second question, Is there any possibility of backordering the domain so I make sure nobody else buys it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.TV` is not a gTLD so ICANN explanations will not fit completely your case.

Is this your domain? If so, contact your registrar, it should be able to help you.

> Is there any way of calculating when the domain is going to release?

Not in general, because it depends on both the TLD, the registry and the registrar.
For example in gTLDs, there is a 45 days auto-renew period. Registrars are free to delete the domain name at any time during that period. Some may do it 10 days after expirations, others 42 days.

> Is there any possibility of backordering the domain so I make sure nobody else buys it?

Contact a registrar, but in general yes there is always a possibility of backordering in gTLDs and most major ccTLDs (`.TV` is a ccTLD even if not sold as one).

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the registrar to ensure to renew it for you. Generally speaking you need to wait for 30 days, after that it will be again available to be booked.